# How do I make angular-ui cell editable on single click?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am trying to make `angular ui-grid cell editable (row)` cell editable on `single click.`

Right Now, Cell becomes editable on double click.

How do I make cell editable on single click?

HTML:

```
<div class="grid testGrid" ui-grid="testGridOptions" ui-grid-edit 
     ui-grid-row-edit style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var columns = [
    { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', cellEditableCondition: function ($scope) { return $scope.row.entity.showRemoved; } }
];
```

Grid options:

```
$scope.testGridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: false,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
    enableSorting: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    rowHeight: 30,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableGridMenu: false,
    showGridFooter: false,

    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editing on single click is automatically added if you use ui-grid's navigation and set `enableCellEditOnFocus` to `true` in your `gridOptions`.

Just add `ui-grid-cellNav` to your grid's `<div>`.

The only thing I don't know is if it's compatible with `ui-grid-row-edit`.

Anyhow take a look at [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav) to know more.

Comment: It IS compatible. I just added the `gridOptions: { enableCellEditOnFocus: true }` on a `<div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ...>`.

The only thing is that for the first edit I still have to double click, only thereafter does single clicking (now) suffice.